# addStyleClass for ad-hoc styles?

Tags: rendering, sapui5

When writing a control, prior to it's rendering you can add css classes to it's html representation's root dom node:

```
FooLayout.prototype.init = function() {
    this.addStyleClass('fooCssClass');
};
```

This will work assuming *writeClasses* is executed during rendering:

```
oRenderManager.writeClasses();
```

--

There is another RenderManager function *writeStyles* which can add in-line styles to the html string buffer:

```
oRenderManager.addStyle("color", "green");
oRenderManager.writeStyles();
```

But there doesn't seem to be an analogous function to *addStyleClass* for adding these at the control level to be picked up during rendering.

Is there a way I can hook into *writeStyles* outside of the renderer?

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask: What styling cannot be applied on control level with a class that can be done with a specific style attribute?

Anyway, the "solution" (which I do not like) would be to add a delegate to the class and do something on onAfterRendering:

```
oControl.addDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: function() {
        this.$().css("opacity", "0.5");
    }.bind(oControl)
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/seqemaqedo/1/edit?js,output

But as I said, I would advice against it because using a good name for a class uses less code and is much easier to read:

```
oControl.addStyleClass("semiTransparent");
```

**Update:**

After our discussion in the comments, here is an example of how to wrap a control that does not support setting width and height.
You still have to write CSS that references the inner control structure, but in this case it is very unlikely that it will change:

http://jsbin.com/lohocaqixi/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I am trying to avoid applying this style post rendering. It also cannot be accomplished with a css class because I am applying absolute positioning values that are calculated in JavaScript

Comment: You cannot apply if "before rendering" because there is no DOM to apply it to. Since UI5 uses string based rendering, only in the onAfterRendering there is actual DOM to apply anything to. The only other solution would be to extend the Control and implement your own renderer.

Comment: Before rendering the dom has not yet generated, but I can still add "style" attributes directly on the html string built up by the renderer. That's what addStyleClass does for css classes...I want to do the same for styles directly

Comment: Exactly. But for that you will need to extend the Control and overwrite the render method. You can call the original render-method in the new renderer if that helps you. You could open a github issue and propose this as an enhancement, but honestly in the last 3 years nobody missed this feature since most use cases  containing dynamic calculations are usually better off using a new custom control, since the DOM of the original control can change with every version as it is not part of the API and must not stay the same.

Comment: I suppose I will need to extend the render function for the control I am extending. It's just disappointing since as you said that will make future upgrades more risky not to mention having to copy-paste code and inject my code somewhere in between

Comment: Maybe you can do it another way: Write a custom control. Add the control you extend now into an aggregtion, set its width and height to 100%. In your renderer, render a div with your style-attributes and inside render the other control using the renderControl-method of the RenderManager. That way you have Control over the size and the HTML output of the other Control does not matter.